# How to solve not find files error after Angular 9 upgarde?

Tags: angular, angular9

After I have upgraded to angular 9 I started to receive many errors like bellow ;

> ERROR in Can't export value CdkScrollableModule in D:/xyz/abc/projectname/node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/index.d.ts from MatDatepickerModule in D:/xyz/abc/projectname/node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/index.d.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!

and much RXJS errors which am not able to solve;

[image: Angular version]

any help is appreciated

Comment: have you tried deleting the entire `node_modules` folder and running `npm/yarn install` afterwards? It's a very common error.

Comment: from which angular version have you tried to update?

Comment: @ionut-t from 8

Comment: I suggest to strictly follow the following guideline when you're upgrading your project to a major release: https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0